# how can i make a script to download files with dynamic links?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, dynamic, wget

I have no experience using linux to make a script, and I need to make a script to download files (multiple files on the same page) whose download links are dynamic. What path should I take or what should I know to be able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having page with links to resources you want to download I suggest trying [Recursive Retrieval Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html) of GNU Wget, to limit download only to resource to which links are present in site you might set level to 1, i.e. do something like

```
wget -r -l 1 http://www.example.com
```